# In VS code, when I try to change the settings it gives me the error message

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

The error message:

```
Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.
```

I'm sure reinstalling the program would fix the issue but I've got a lot of extensions and stuff already installed so I'd rather fix the issue.

These are my current JSON settings:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Live Server Web Extension",
    "version": "1.3.0",
    "description": " Makes your existing server live. This is a browser extension that helps you to live reload feature for dynamic pages",
    "icons": {
        "96": "./img/icon.png",
        "128": "./img/icon128.png"
    },
    "author": "Ritwick Dey",
    "short_name": "Live Server Web Extension",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "reload.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "./popup/popup.html",
        "default_icon": "./img/icon.png",
        "default_title": "Live Server"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [

        ".vscode/**",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass",
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.root": ,
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-palenight",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Palenight High Contrast",
    "editor.rulers": [94]
    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have an extra square bracket at the end and there's an empty value if it's supposed to be empty just remove the `<--- Here is a missing parameter` and ignore it, leaving it with empty double quotes (as in the JSON below). Otherwise, remove the comment and add the value you want. Try this:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Live Server Web Extension",
    "version": "1.3.0",
    "description": " Makes your existing server live. This is a browser extension that helps you to live reload feature for dynamic pages",
    "icons": {
        "96": "./img/icon.png",
        "128": "./img/icon128.png"
    },
    "author": "Ritwick Dey",
    "short_name": "Live Server Web Extension",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "reload.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "./popup/popup.html",
        "default_icon": "./img/icon.png",
        "default_title": "Live Server"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [
        ".vscode/**",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass",
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.root": "", <--- Here is a missing parameter
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-palenight",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Palenight High Contrast",
    "editor.rulers": [
        94
    ]
}
```

Comment: No this did not fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the solution. Check that there's a property with a missing value